# OneNote JS API - How to add a page to a specific section by title

Tags: onenote-api

I want to add a page to a specific section, but the documentation only gives examples of how to call the current page ie

context.application.**getActiveSection()**.addPage;

But i cannot figure out for the life of me how I would choose a specific page by title. Any help would be much appreicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the active notebook, then the sections in the active notebook, then look for one with the name you're looking for.

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/onenote/notebook

```
OneNote.run(function (context) {
    // Gets the active notebook.
    var notebook = context.application.getActiveNotebook();

    // Queue a command to get immediate child sections of the notebook. 
    var childSections = notebook.sections;

    // Queue a command to load the childSections. 
    context.load(childSections);

    // Run the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    return context.sync()
        .then(function() {
            $.each(childSections.items, function(index, childSection) {
                console.log("Immediate child section name: " + childSection.name);
            });            
        });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for